# How do I use UIImagePickerController camera image to update my UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I need the UIImageView on my CollectionViewCell to update with the camera image Using UIImagePickerController camera option. I think all of my outlets and identifiers are correct. Here is my UIViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class CameraVC: BaseViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBAction func importImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true) {
        //After it is complete
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageArray.append(image)
    } 
    else {
        //Error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    getPhotos()
}

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
func getPhotos() {

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fecthResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

        if fecthResult.count > 0 {

            for i in 0..<fecthResult.count {

                imgManager.requestImage(for: fecthResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                })
            }
        }
         else {
            print("You are without any photos.")
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.addSlideMenuButton()
    self.title = "Camera"
    getPhotos()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

and here is my UICollectionViewCell code:

```
import UIKit

class CameraImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var thumb: UIImageView!    

    func configureCell() { }
}
```

-Thanks for the assistance!-

Answer (score 0):

Update your following method:

```
func getPhotos() {

let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

if let fecthResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

    if fecthResult.count > 0 {

        for i in 0..<fecthResult.count {

            imgManager.requestImage(for: fecthResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                image, error in
                self.imageArray.append(image!)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
     else {
        print("You are without any photos.")
    }
}
}
```

You have to reload the collection view after appending image to array:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

will get you required functionality